# Put string of "00:00" into DateTime so it is 12pm

Tags: c#, date, datetime, time

I can't seem to enter 12pm into the DateTime.

This is my Code:

```
string a = "00:00";
DateTime applyClock = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "H:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

The string has to be '00:00' (it will be a 24h format).

I tried everything I could think of in the DateTime.ParseExact. I tried "hh:mm", "H:mm", "HH:mm", "H:mm:ss"(format error). I read that "H:mm" or "HH:mm" should be the solution but still 'applyClock' is at 12 am instead of pm.

How can I have a string of "00:00" and put this time into 'applyClock' ? (01:00 and so on works fine)

Comment: Do you just want `DateTime.Now.Date`? _"The string has to be '00:00' (it will be a 24h format)."_ - also note that `DateTime` objects do not have a human-readable representation stored in them, so any human-readable date you see is a (thread) culture-sensitive conversion to a string.

Comment: 12:00 is 12pm (midday), 00:00 is 12am (midnight)

Comment: @phuzi I just entered "string a = "12:00" - It is 12 am.

Comment: Did you use the "HH:mm" format?

Comment: @phuzi yes I also have tried using "HH:mm"

Comment: @axbeit If `DateTime.Now.Date` isn't what you need, please can you tell me why? I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if I do `DateTime.ParseExact("00:00", "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` then I get 21/05/2019 00:00:00 which is 12 am today. Not sure why you see 12pm!

Comment: @Clint Have seen it. Have tried it. applyClock still shows "12 am" instead of "12 pm".

Comment: you are doing it right! but 00:00 in 24h format is 12:00 am (midnight) and 12:00 is 12:00 (midday)

Comment: @John I want to have a string that contains "00:00" in it. I want to apply this time into 'applyClock' so 'applyClock' has "12 pm" as it's time. But for some reason 'applyClock' time is 12 am if my string is "00:00"

Comment: 1) As I explained before, `DateTime` doesn't contain a string value. `DateTime` also _always_ has a time component, since the entire date and time is internally represented by a single `long` value. 2) 00:00 _is_ 12am (i.e. the time when most people might be in bed asleep, not the time you eat lunch).

Comment: That's wrong though 00:00 is 12 ___am___ not 12 ___pm___

Comment: @axbeit then you're doing something non-standard; 00:00 in all time formats is *always* 12 AM (midnight), never 12 PM (noon)

Comment: I see my problem. I'm stupid. Sorry. Thanks for the help. In my mind I had 12 pm as midnight, which is wrong obviously.

Comment: @axbeit No worries :)

Comment: You shouldn't be so hard on yourself, I wouldn't say you're stupid, we've all been there and stared with our blind eyes at something, not seeing the problem even though it was easy to spot all along.